# Make existing or already installed root file system encrypted

Tags: linux, archlinux, manjaro, luks

I'm having an existing manjaro linux installation and my root file system is not encrypted. How  do i encrypt my file system without reinstall or lossing any data. Is it possible to copy root file system to another encrypted drive using live cd then make that as my root file system. Can anyone guide me on this.

/dev/sda1 is my root file system which is of size 80gb
/dev/sda2 is my swap which is of size 4GB

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I did not know that thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

superuser.com is more relevant for this kind of questions.

Check out [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/902397/270154), which uses [cryptsetup-reencrypt](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/cryptsetup-reencrypt.8.html) to do an offline in-place encryption of a block device, e.g. a partition.

If that doesn't suit you, you can also create an encrypted partition and copy files using `rsync -a /old /new`.